# How to capture multiple url parameters using @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc

I have this method:

```
@GetMapping("/restaurant")
public List<Restaurant> list(@RequestParam(required = false) String nameRestaurant, @RequestParam(required = false)String nameProduct){
    if (nameRestaurant== null && nameProduct== null ) {
        return restaurantRepository.findAll();
    }
     else if (!nameProduct.isEmpty()){
         return restaurantRepository.findByNameProduct(nameProduct);
    }
    else {
        return restaurantRepository.findByNameRestaurant(nameRestaurant);
    }
}
```

Only 'IF' and 'ELSE IF' work and return JSON, 'ELSE' always returns 500(NullPointerException). If I invert 'ELSE IF' with 'ELSE', what will be in 'ELSE IF' will work and 'ELSE' will not, is there any why?

Comment: Add the url you tried for which you get 500 and show us full error stacktrace

Comment: NullPointerException, when I try to use the findbynameRestaurant

Comment: That doesn't give my answer

Comment: Consider rethinking your if-else-structure as [Pedrohreis suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63451329/896249) and maybe try a simple `System.out.println` before you enter the ifs, to see what the params look like. It would be easier to see what is wrong when you showed us the URL (with the request parameters!) that you are trying.

Comment: 2020-08-17 10:51:24.425 ERROR 2344 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a null checker in your validation. The first if checks if `nameRestaurant` AND `nameProduct` are `null`, meaning that during the `else` / `else if` `nameRestaurant` OR `nameProduct` might be `null` (possibly leading to `NullPointerException`).

Probably changing your code to the following would work:

```java
@GetMapping("/restaurant")
public List<restaurant> list(@RequestParam(required = false) String nameRestaurant,
                             @RequestParam(required = false) String nameProduct) {
   if (nameRestaurant != null && !nameRestaurant.isEmpty()) {
      return restaurantRepository.findByNameRestaurant(nameRestaurant);
   }
   if (nameProduct != null && !nameProduct.isEmpty()) {
      return restaurantRepository.findByNameProduct(nameProduct);
   }
   
   return restaurantRepository.findAll();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use urls instead:

```
// Get all restaurants
@GetMapping("/restaurant")
/restaurant

// Get restaurant by name
@GET
@Path("/restaurant")
@PathParam("name")String name
/restaurant/{name}

// Get product by restaurant and product name
@GET
@Path("/restaurant")
@PathParam("name")String name, @PathParam("product")String product
/restaurant/{name}/{product}
```